# Terraform and DigitalOcean: assign volume to specific droplet created with count parameter

Tags: digital-ocean, terraform

just started exploring terraform to spin up droplets and volumes on digital ocean.

My question is to know the right way to do the following:

- create a certain number of droplet instances using `count` within `digitalocean_droplet`resource named `ubuntu16`
- assign a `digitalocean_volume` only to one or a subset of previously created droplets.

How to do it?I was assuming to use `droplets_id` property on `digitalocean_volume` resource. Something like:

```
resource "digitalocean_volume" "foovolume" {
  ...
  droplet_ids = ["${digitalocean_droplet.ubuntu16.0.id}"]
}
```

Validating it with `terraform validate` I got:

`Error: digitalocean_volume.foovolume: "droplet_ids": this field cannot be set`

Any advice? Thanks to any inputs on it.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

The way the Terraform provider for DigtialOcean is currently implemented requires that you take the opposite approach. You can specify which volumes are attached to which Droplets by defining the `volume_ids` of the Droplet resource. For example:

```
resource "digitalocean_volume" "volume" {
    region      = "nyc3"
    count       = 3
    name        = "volume-${count.index + 1}"
    size        = 100
    description = "an example volume"
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
    count      = 3
    image      = "ubuntu-17-10-x64"
    name       = "web-${count.index + 1}"
    region     = "nyc3"
    size       = "1gb"
    volume_ids = ["${element(digitalocean_volume.volume.*.id, count.index)}"]
}
```

If you look at the [docs for the volume resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/r/volume.html#droplet_ids), you'll see that `droplet_ids` is a "computed" field. This means that you are unable to set the field, and that its value is computed by Terraform via the provider's API.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know it works on the opposite side. With your approach I will get 3 droplets and 3 volumes, one per droplet. My question is, 3 droplets created with count and 1 volume attached to just 1 droplet.